# I want to return a value AND raise an exception, does this mean I'm doing something wrong?

Tags: python, architecture, exception

I have a number of functions that parse data from files, usually returning a list of results.

If I encounter a dodgy line in the file, I want to soldier on and process the valid lines, and return them. But I also want to report the error to the calling function. The reason I want to report it is so that the calling function can notify the user that the file needs looking at. I don't want to start doing GUI things in the parse function, as that seems to be a big violation of separation of concerns. The parse function does not have access to the console I'm writing error messages to anyway.

This leaves me wanting to return the successful data, but also raise an exception because of the error, which clearly I can't do.

Consider this code:

```
try:
    parseResult = parse(myFile)
except MyErrorClass, e:
    HandleErrorsSomehow(str(e))

def parse(file): #file is a list of lines from an actual file
    err = False
    result = []

    for lines in file:
        processedLine = Process(line)
        if not processedLine:
            err = True
        else
            result.append(processedLine)
    return result
    if err:
        raise MyErrorClass("Something went wrong")
```

Obviously the last three lines make no sense, but I can't figure out a nice way to do this. I guess I could do `return (err, result)`, and call it like

```
parseErr, parseResult = parse(file)
if parseErr:
    HandleErrorsSomehow()
```

But returning error codes seems un-pythonic enough, let alone returning tuples of error codes and actual result values.

The fact that I feel like I want to do something so strange in an application that shouldn't really be terribly complicated, is making me think I'm probably doing something wrong. Is there a better solution to this problem? Or is there some way that I can use `finally` to return a value and raise an exception at the same time?

Comment: In this case, I would probably return a tuple `processedData,errorInformation`, with `errorInformation` being an empty string if no error occurred. Another option would be to use a callback function, called with some error information if an error occurs - if the caller doesn't care, it could pass `None` as the callback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nobody says the *only* valid way to treat an "error" is to throw an exception.

In your design the caller wants two pieces of information: (1) the valid data, (2) whether an error occurred (and probably something about what went wrong where, so it can format a useful error message). That is a completely valid and above-ground case for returning a pair of values.

An alternative design would be to pass a mutable collection *down* to the function as a parameter and let it fill any error messages it wants to emit into that. That will often simplify the plumbing in the caller, especially if there are several layers of calls between the parser and the code that knows how to do something with the error messages afterwards.

Comment: Your last sentence- that was one of my main reasons for looking for a better way to do this. Hadn't thought of using an 'out parameter.' (Do they have a better name?)

Comment: While emitting warnings may have been more elegant in an ideal world, the fact that Jython is only up to 2.5 made it impractical for me. I ended up passing down a list to be filled by the parse function. This works especially well in places where I call a few different parse functions in a row, and then I can iterate over the whole warning list once they're all done. I like this a lot more than returning tuples and checking separate return values.

Comment: @CamJackson For situations like this. I've frequently found that passing down a callback with a specified call signature works better than passing a raw list. That way it's easy to abstract the implementation away from the internals, as well as put in a stub callback when the caller doesn't care to get errors back. Frequently, it can be as simple as passing in the bound `.append` method of the list you want to add to. It makes it clearer that something is being passed back ("out" params aren't always obvious), and allows the caller to do complex processing at the moment of the error.

Comment: @Eli Collins I'd tried to stay away from passing a callback because I didn't want the parse function to know/care about what to do upon errors, it would just list them. However, I hadn't thought of just passing `.append` in, which actually goes further in the direction I wanted. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

[Emit a warning](http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html) instead, and let the code decide how to handle it.

Comment: that's cute.  had no idea that module existed.  it looks like warnings can be connected to python's logging, which could in turn be connected to the gui.

Comment: This looks promising, looking into this now. Only thing is, I'm using Jython, which doesn't seem to have `warnings.catch_warnings()`, so I'm not sure how I'm meant to handle the warnings. Can I just try-catch them like an exception?

Comment: Hmmm, I read through [this](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/ExceptionHandlingDebug.html#issuing-warnings) but it doesn't say anything about how the calling function can capture the warnings. Unless I use a filter to turn warnings into exceptions, but then I'm back where I started aren't I? Do you know how to handle warnings without using `catch_warnings()`?

Comment: ["You may replace this function with an alternative implementation by assigning to `warnings.showwarning`."](http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html#warnings.showwarning)

Comment: OK, but what would I make it do that would accomplish a try-catch kind of idiom? I could make it just append warnings to some list somewhere, but then I have to check it manually all the time, rather than getting the 'interrupt' kind of functionality of an exception. At that point I may as well just forgo warnings and return a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible design is to invert control, by passing the error handler in as a parameter.

(Also, don't feel like you have to tell Python how to accumulate data in a list. It knows already. It's not hard to make a list comprehension work here.)

```
def sample_handler():
    print "OMG, I wasn't expecting that; oh well."

parseResult = parse(myFile, sample_handler)

def parse(file, handler): #file is a list of lines from an actual file
    result = [Process(line) for line in data]
    if not all(result): handler() # i.e. if there are any false-ish values
    result = filter(None, result) # remove false-ish values if any
    return result
```

Comment: The format of my data files is a bit more complicated than I let on, so I actually do have to iterate over the list manually, but that's a cool method. Python is full of pleasant surprises!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on caller design. using callbacks might be reasonable:

```
def got_line(line):
    print 'Got valid line', line

def got_error(error):
    print 'got error', error

def parse(file, line, error):
    for lines in file:
        processedLine = Process(line)
        if not processedLine:
            error(MyErrorClass("Something went wrong"))
        else
            line(processedLine)


parse(some_file, got_line, got_error)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to propose an alternative solution; using a class.

```
class MyParser(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.warnings = []

    def parse(self, file):
        ...
```

Now the parse function can set warnings to the `warnings` list, and the user can check this list if they so desire.

As soon as my functions start becoming more advanced than just "process this and return my value" I like to consider using a class instead. It makes for great clustering of related code into one object and it often makes for cleaner code and simpler usage than functions returning tuples of information.

Answer (score 0):

I come from the .Net world, so not sure how this translates into Python...

In cases like yours (where you want to process numerous items in a single call) I'd return a `MyProcessingResults` object that held two collections, for example:

- `MyProcessingResults.ProcessedLines` - holds all the valid data you parsed.
- `MyProcessingResults.Errors` - holds all the errors (on the assumption that you have more than one and you want to explicitly know about all of them).

Comment: Sounds like this would be akin to just returning a tuple of the results and any errors. In python a tuple can hold objects of differing types, so there's no need to define a class that contains the 2 objects I want to pass back if that's how I want to do it.